# Заполнение структуры данных (ключ, значение) напрямую

Tags: java

Есть ли в java возможность заполнить какую-либо структуру данных(ключ, значение), например map напрямую без использования методов, если данные статические и изменяться не будут.
Что-то по типу:
`HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{"a", 0 },{"b", 20 },{"d", 30 },{"c", 40 }}`

Comment: Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("a", 0, "b", 1, "c", 2);

Answer (score 0):

Для JDK 8 есть хак вида:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{ 
    put("a", 0);
    put("b", 20);
    put("d", 30);
    put("c", 40);
}}
```

По сути в этом коде создается анонимный класс-наследник `HashMap` и в нем реализуется блок инициализации с четырьмя вызовами `put`

Но лучше использовать библиотечные `Immutable` классы, по типу [ImmutableMap](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) из guava

В JDK >= 9 появились методы инициализации в интерфейсе `Map`:

```
Map stringMap = Map.of("a", 0, "b", 20, "c", 30, "d", 40);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Пример заполнения структуры данных **HashMap** в **Java**.
>
> Зачитываем файл **Json** с помощью библиотеки **jackson**.

**media.json**

```
{
  "a": 0,
  "b": 20,
  "d": 30,
  "c": 40
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java**

```
File file = new File(Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("media.json").getFile());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

HashMap<String, Object> media = mapper.readValue(file, HashMap.class);

System.out.println(media); // {a=0, b=20, c=40, d=30}
```

---

**UPD:** В общем случае на выходе получается `HashMap<String, Object>`, но в данном случае можно смело поставить `HashMap<String, Integer>`.